# SetTimeout for multiple real-time flot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I want to be able to have multiple real-time flot charts. I have it working with one flot chart where everything is updated real time via this function:

```
        function updateOnce(plot)
        {
            plot.setData([{ label: 'G-force', data: getRandomData(), lines: { show: true } }]);
            plot.setupGrid();//sensorPlots[i]
            plot.draw();

            setTimeout(function () { updateOnce(plot); }, 30);
    }
```

Now the problem I have is that I am dynamically generating the `plot` and adding it to an array. How could I setup this type of function to iterate every the array and run this function for every plot in the array without affecting the others?

I've tried this:

```
        function updateOnce()
        {
            $.each(sensorPlots, function (i, val) {
                val.setData([{ label: 'G-force', data: getRandomData(), lines: { show: true } }]);
                val.setupGrid();//sensorPlots[i]
                val.draw();
                setTimeout(updateOnce, 30);
            });

        }

sensorPlots is an array filled with `plots`
```

but then this causes my graph to move faster and faster with every `plot` that I add.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are declaring a new timeout for every plot every time the timeout function is run. This will lead to the function being called with exponentially increasing frequency which is very bad... What if you do it like this:

```
function updateOnce() {
    $.each(sensorPlots, function (i, val) {
        val.setData([{ label: 'G-force', data: getRandomData(), lines: { show: true}}]);
        val.setupGrid();//sensorPlots[i]
        val.draw();
    });
    setTimeout(updateOnce, 30);        
}

updateOnce();
```

Comment: I don't understand `setTimeout` well enough so that's probably why I'm struggling. Also I just tried this solution but it seems the function neever gets called

Comment: I'm sorry. I was apparently tired when i answered yesterday. You still need to have the setTimeout inside the update function, but not inside the each loop. This way you will set up exactly one new timeout every time the update function is run instead of one for each plot. I have updated my answer.